# How to create dynamic custom style on mat -dialog on each mat-table row with top triangle in Angular - Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-table, mat-dialog

Here is my sample code.
[Please find my working sample code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahbpn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayments%2Fpayments.component.ts)

**I need to set triangle on right top corner in mat-dialog box - Angular.**

I am getting top right corner triangle dialog box using static css on last row.
But here not able to get on each row on change request button click.

**The below code is for the Dialog box Component**

```
openDialog(Id, Currency, Amount, Reason, StatusDescription, payment, event) {

  let targetAttr = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

dialogConfig.data = {
  Id: Id,
  Reason: Reason,
  StatusDescription: StatusDescription
}; 
dialogConfig.position = {
  top: targetAttr.y + targetAttr.height + 10 + "px",
  left: targetAttr.x - targetAttr.width - 20 + "px"
};
  dialogConfig.panelClass = ['my-panel','arrow-top']; 

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditingDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("Dialog output:", data)
   }
  );
 }
```

**The Below code is from style.scss**

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
 @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

 .my-panel {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    color: #fff;

 }
  .my-panel.arrow-top {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
 .my-panel.arrow-top:after {
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     right: 100px;
     top: 365px;
     border-top: none;
     border-right: 15px solid transparent;
     border-left: 15px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 15px solid gray;
    }
```

**I am getting like this.**
[image]

[image]

**But I want dialog box with upper arrow on each row under change request button click event**
[image]

Comment: Can someone look here?